# android writing to sdcard

Tags: java, android, file

I am not able to write to the SDCARD.  I can not create a Directory or a File, what am I missing  I have this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

And this in my code

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {   
                // Create a directory; all ancestor directories must exist
                    boolean success = (new File("/sdcard/Methods/")).mkdirs();
                //create file   
                    try{
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/Methods/Method 1 Square.xml");
                    File file = myFile;
                        // Create file if it does not exist
                        boolean success1 = file.createNewFile();}   
                    catch (IOException e) 
                        {}
                //write to file
                    try {
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/Methods/Method 1 Square.xml"));
                        out.write ("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                        out.write ("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
                        out.write ("Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"");
                        out.close();
                    } // end try
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                    } // end catch

            } // end public

        }); // end SAVE Button
```

Comment: Are you getting errors then? What's your logcat say? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: because the directory or file is not on my sdcard.  I guess it is time to learn logcat.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st Thing:**

Just check the 'success' variable, whether it returns really **true**.

**2nd Thing:**

As you have hard coded the /sdcard, Instead i suggest you get the directory using: **`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`** because in some devices the sd-card root directory is **/mnt/sdcard** so the above method to get root directory.

**3rd Thing:**

You should first check whether the SD-card is mounted or not.

### Example:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir/subdir");  // in your case, just give /Methods

dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");  // in your case, just give "Method 1 Square.xml"

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: I am a rookie at java and using eclipse and have no idea how to do what you indicted.  I have struggled with every new idea.  Today I created the binning of an excel.xml file and added 500 lines and trying to write.  I use the android emulator and my phone for testing and wish I knew ,ore about eclipse.  I am off to learn about checking variable.  Thank you.

Comment: try the above example in your way.

Comment: Your second thing fixed the problem!.  I guess I will have to figure out what Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() so I can be sure my apk works everywhere.  THANK YOU

Comment: @WmBurkert  yeh cheers :) its a silly mistake that most androider do if they dont know about the same. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that the directories in the path do not exist. With that `FileWriter` constructor, if the file does not exist it is created but that doesn't include the directories.