# how to writer on External SdCard (mnt/external1)

Tags: android

i want to write on external sdcard (path: /mnt/external1/). i can read that path, but when i create a new folder on it pro grammatically it not create. i have already declare read write permission in manifeast.xml.

when i write code f.mkdir(); it return false;
and when i create an outputStream obj for that path and try to write something on that it through an exception Permission denied.

Note: My aim is to write something on external sdcrad which path is /mnt/external1 .

plz give me some solution .

my code is

```
public int createFolder(String FolderName)
{
    File f = new File("/mnt/external1"+FolderName);
    if(!f.exists())
    {   
        if(f.mkdirs())
        {
            files= getFiles(path);
            imageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return 1;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Any exception? logcat output?

Comment: i have attach code with my questino

Comment: hello Paresh actually when i use try cahch it give me exception Permission denied for that path only. there is no creash in my application

Comment: Don't use static coded directory path: instead use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get root directory of your external storage

Comment: Go through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998185/android-writing-to-sdcard/7998313#7998313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has been an issue for Xoom tablets (at least) since 3.2.  Reference [18501](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18501) or [18559](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18559) on the Android bug list.  You might have to rely solely on the path that getExternalStorageDirectory() returns for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void createFolder(String FolderName)
{
    File f = new File(new File("/mnt/external1"), FolderName);
    if(!f.exists())
    {   
        f.mkdirs();
     }
}
```

This should work, but it is hardcoded for motorola xoom, tested.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code if it works

```
public int createFolder(String FolderName)
{
    File f = new File(Enviornment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FolderName);
    if(!f.exists())
    {   
        if(f.mkdirs())
        {
            files= getFiles(path);
            imageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return 1;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: hi   this code is for create the folder in the internal memory (/mnt/sdcard) but i am talking about the external sdcard which we atta ch in our externally and the path for that ("/mnt/external1"). It is really a big problem If can solve it then i really thankful to u

Comment: This is the code for saving to extrnal storage or better to say in the SDCard its also mentioned in method call i.e external

Comment: i am using motorola xoom in it have internal memory and it showing it as the Folder name sdcard in /mnt/sdcard/. so it is its internal memory.

Comment: Dont know about Xoom but its a rule of thumb that a SDCard is generally externally mounted

Answer (score 1):

try this way. this is the example not perfect code for your but you can get some idea/help

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
   String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"myfolder";
   boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
   if(!exists) new File(path).mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Pratik this code is for create the folder in the internal memory (/mnt/sdcard) but i am talking about the external sdcard which we atta ch in our externally and the path for that ("/mnt/external1").  It is really a big problem If can solve it then i really thankful to u.

Comment: this is for the external not for the internal see the function getExternalStorageState();